# How to make a phase diagram (vector plot) using results from NDSolve?

Tags: plotting

I solved the next differential equations using `NDSolve`, so I got two solutions `ϕ[t]` and `H[t]`.

Differential equation:

```
s1 = 
  NDSolve[
    {ϕ'[t]^2 (1 + 6 η H[t]^2) - 2 η H'[t] ϕ'[t]^2 + 
      4 η (α + 3) H[t]^2  ϕ'[t]^2 + 2 M H'[t] == 0 
        /. {η -> 1, M -> 1, α -> -0.02}, 
     ϕ''[t] == -(α + 3) H[t] ϕ'[t] /. α -> -0.02, 
     H[0] == 1, ϕ[0] == 0.2, ϕ'[0] == 10^(-2)}, 
    {H, ϕ}, {t, -4, 4}]
```

I want to get the phase diagram so I use:

```
VectorPlot[{ϕ[t] /. s1, ϕ'[t] /. s1}, {ϕ, -4, 4}, {ϕ, -4, 4}]
```

but I do not get the plot.

Comment: maybe `ParametricPlot[{\[Phi][t] /. s1[[1]], \[Phi]'[t] /. 
   s1[[1]]}, {t, -1.33, 4}, AspectRatio -> 1]`?

Comment: I got a line, I think that It has to be with VectorPlot.

Comment: The expression `{ϕ[t], ϕ'[t]}` doesn't represent a vector field. You can not use `VectorPlot`.

Comment: You didn't mention that `NDSolve` issued warnings.

Comment: My suggestions are: 1) use `NSolveValue` instead of `NSolve`, and you will get functions, which can be more convenient for further use, rather than rules; 2) give a proper interval of `t`, letting no warnings be issued; 3) use `ParametricPlot` to make the plot.